# How to correctly set-up mockito in the test class?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have written the tests   `handleFirebaseMessagesBigText()` and `handleFirebaseMessagesBigPicture()` using Mockito. 
   Under `@Before` , in the function `init()` , if I don't comment out the last 2 lines, these 2 tests and all my other tests also fail for some reason. If I comment out these 2 lines, the 2 tests above fail. I'm not able to make these tests work. How do I fix this?

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    private Context context;

    @Mock
    private HandleFirebaseMessages handleFirebaseMessages;

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityTestRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Before
    public void init() {
        context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
        //MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        //handleFirebaseMessages = new HandleFirebaseMessages();
    }

 @Test
    public void handleFirebaseMessagesBigText() {
        RemoteMessage remoteMessage = new RemoteMessage.Builder("token").addData("type","1").build();
        handleFirebaseMessages.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Map<String,String> data = new HashMap<>() ;
        data.put("type","1");
        Mockito.verify(handleFirebaseMessages).buildNotificationBigText(data);
    }

    @Test
    public void handleFirebaseMessagesBigPicture() {
        RemoteMessage remoteMessage = new RemoteMessage.Builder("token").addData("type","2").build();
        handleFirebaseMessages.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Map<String,String> data = new HashMap<>() ;
        data.put("type","2");
                 Mockito.verify(handleFirebaseMessages).buildNotificationBigPicture(data);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I'm getting the following error for both my test methods:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

As you can see in the code, I'm passing the key value pair "type"-"1" in my test functions to `onMessageReceived()` . And subsequently I get these 2 errors.
     However, if I use the firebase console to send a message with this exact key-value pair, everything works all right. So I'm guessing there's something wrong with the way I'm using `RemoteMessage` to send my key value pair to `onMessageReceived()`.

Comment: Which failure message are you getting?

Comment: @alayor Please look at the revised question.

Comment: Try using `@Spy` instead of `@Mock` in `HandleFirebaseMessages`. Otherwise, you are mocking every method in that object.

Answer (score 0):

You are already mocking your instance variable `handleFirebaseMessages` with the `@Mock` annotation, so you do not need to create an instance yourself (Mockito will).

Try with this:

```
@Before
public void init() {
    context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    //handleFirebaseMessages = new HandleFirebaseMessages();
}
```

Comment: Keeping the line `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` causes all my tests to fail- including these two.